# Regex for Vbscript Functions/Sub calls

Tags: python, regex, vbscript

I am trying to detect function calls in a vbscript using Python and get the function name. I'm no interested in object methods, just simple functions and Subs. I'm using re with re.I flag.

The pattern :

```
((?!function )|(?!\\.))(\w+?)[\(](.)*?[\)])
```

What should i do

```
Function Call111(parm1)       ----> should ignore it
X2 = Call222()                ----> Should get it : Call222
X3 = Obj.Call333()            ----> should ignore it
```

I don't understand where I'm getting it wrong! Any pointers are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\bfunction )(?<!\.)\b(\w+)\(
```

Use `lookbehind` instead of `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/89

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<!\bfunction )(?<!\.)\b(\w+)\(', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "Function Call111(parm1)       ----> should ignore it\nX2 = Call222()                ----> Should get it : Call222\nX3 = Obj.Call333() "

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: The pattern is perfect, but in pyhon i get the fixed width error. I'm using 2.7.  Any pointers?

Comment: Yeees! The evil regex has been defeated! Thank you very much! I should read some more on regex.